# Matching only 5xx using regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find all numbers that are in between 500-599. I'm very new to regex, I came up with this :

```
5[0-9][0-9]+
```

This is working fine, matching `566,577,500`. But it also matches `6578`. Which I don't want.

#### Edit:

Here is my file contents:

```
asd 554
sad
sads

dsa


456

sa
d

dsa
asda
d500
521
519 asdasd
524 asdasdsdsadsdasd sadsadsadasdsd asdsa dsa dsadsad sad asdas dsa sad sad asds a 543
```

As many suggested I tried :

```
grep "^5[0-9]{2}$" test
```

which isn't finding any numbers at all!

How do I put a constraint on this?

Comment: The curly-brace notation is part of the extended regular expressions, you need to use `egrep` or supply `grep` with the `-E` switch.

Comment: Skip the curly and add another "[0-9]". The "^" and the "$" means that you are matching the start and the end of each line, which I see in your example, is not what you want. Therefor, using "5[0-9][0-9]" as my answer suggests, should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to match 5xx **only** on a line, and not when **5xx** occurs as a part of **x5xx**,

```
^5\d{2}$
```

> \d = Digit
>
> ^ = beginning of line
>
> $ = end of line

**EDIT:**

Based on additional details in the question, you have a variable number of spaces at the beginning of the line, so, you want the following instead:

`\s*5\d{2}\s`

Matches spaces on either side of 5xx.

Comment: At regexpal, you are putting a newline at the end of the regex. That is why it is failing for you. It works for me on regexpal and http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Just remove the newline from the regex once you copy it there.

Answer (score 5):

With `grep` the easiest way is to use `-w` to only match whole words:

```
grep --color=always -w "5[0-9][0-9]" test
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the + sign:

```
5[0-9][0-9]
```

This will match "5" succeeded by two numbers, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe a bit more accurately what you want to happen with e.g. 6578? If you want 578 in the output (because after "6" there is a *sequence of characters* matching your format 5xx) you can simply do

```
grep -o "5[0-9][0-9]"
```

Note that unlike other answers, the `-o` flag emits multiple numbers from a single line if needed.

If, on the other hand, you want to match *words* of format 5xx, you can add `-w` flag, too:

```
grep -o -w "5[0-9][0-9]"
```

For more complex rules for matching, you want to use `-E` flag instead and use possibly a much more complex regex.